# Which is a better sentence out of these two?

Tags: meaning, difference

Original sentence:

> The fabrication is done properly to avoid chances of voids present in a crystal lattice.

I think it is equivalent to

> The fabrication is done properly to avoid chances of voids **that are** present in a crystal lattice.

But it is not important that the voids may always be present and the above sentence signifies that the voids are always present, so may I put it like this as given below?

> The fabrication is done properly to avoid chances of voids **that may be** present in a crystal lattice.

Which one should be preferred or more fine?

Answer (score 1):

When describing a chance in terms of probability, we use *of* (as do your sentences), so any uses of verbs should be gerunds.

Therefore, the correct sentence is

> The fabrication is done properly to avoid the chances of voids **being** present in a crystal lattice.

Answer (score 1):

The original sentence doesn't make much sense. May I suggest:

> "The fabrication is done properly to avoid chances of voids **being**
>   present in a crystal lattice."

(i.e. "voids being present" is what we are avoiding.)

or

> The fabrication is done properly to avoid chances of voids **which** may be present in a crystal lattice.

(i.e. "voids" is what we are avoiding and voids may be present.)

Answer (score 0):

Your third sentence using "... that may be ..." is certainly the clearest.

Your second sentence does imply that voids are always present by using a definite 'that are'. However, this is offset by your use of '... chances of ...', which allows for uncertainty.

On a related point, I would say your use of 'chances' can be improved, to:
'The fabrication is done properly to avoid the chance of voids that may be present ...'.

Comment: I think you last suggested sentence would be even clearer as, "The fabrication is done properly to avoid any voids that may be present ...'.".  The "may be" in the sentence provides the uncertainty.

Comment: @Readin Fair point. I was trying to leave the original sentence broadly unchanged, to keep focus on the minor change I was suggesting. Were we to make larger changes, your version is better.

Answer (score 0):

I believe you are trying to say something like, "We do the fabrication properly because it helps us succeed even when there are voids in the crystal lattice".  If that is the case, then you could say

"Fabrication is done properly so that potential voids in the crystal lattice do not create a problem."

Whatever you do, do not say "chances of voids". The meaning is very unclear.